# Converting a 12h clock to 24h clock

Tags: beginner, parsing, datetime, formatting, rust

I started picking up Rust on my free time, and I'm curious about what style errors have I made and where should I improve as a programmer.

The problem is from HackerRank and very simple: there is a fixed-format input of time in 12 hour format (`07:05:45PM`), and the objective is to convert it to 24 hour format (`19:05:45`).

My own first impressions:

- The problem is very simple, but the code seems too lengthy?
- I'm nesting `match` constructs, and it doesn't seem concise.

---

```
use std::io::{stdin, BufRead, Error, ErrorKind, Result};

struct Time {
    hour: u8,
    minute: u8, 
    second: u8
}

impl Time {
    pub fn from_12h(time : String) -> Result<Time> {
        assert!(time.chars().count() == 10);
        let hour : String = time.chars().take(2).collect();  
        let minute : String = time.chars().skip(3).take(2).collect();
        let second : String = time.chars().skip(6).take(2).collect();
        let period : String = time.chars().skip(8).take(2).collect();

        match Time::hour_from_12h_to_24h(hour.parse::<u8>().unwrap(), period) {
            Ok(hour_24h) =>
                Ok(Time {
                    hour: hour_24h,
                    minute: minute.parse::<u8>().unwrap(),
                    second: second.parse::<u8>().unwrap()
                }),
            Err(e) => Err(e),
        }
    }

    fn hour_from_12h_to_24h(hour : u8, period : String) -> Result<u8> {
        match period.as_ref() {
            "AM" => Ok(hour % 12),
            "PM" => Ok(hour % 12 + 12),
            _ => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, format!("invalid period {}", period))),
        }
    }

    pub fn to_24h(&self) -> String {
        format!("{:02}:{:02}:{:02}", self.hour, self.minute, self.second)
    }
}

fn main() {
    match read_12h_time() {
        Ok(time_12h) =>
            match Time::from_12h(time_12h) {
                Ok(time) => println!("{}", time.to_24h()),
                Err(err) => println!("error: {}", err)
            },
        Err(err) => println!("input error: {}", err),
    }
}

fn read_12h_time() -> Result<String> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    match read_line(&mut buffer) {
        Ok(length) =>
            match length {
                10 => Ok(buffer),
                _ => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidInput, format!("expected 10 characters, got {}", length)))
            },
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}

fn read_line(buffer : &mut String) -> Result<usize> {
    let stdin = stdin();
    let mut handle = stdin.lock();
    handle.read_line(buffer)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your code doesn't really work when used by humans. The first thing I did was run the code and type in a time, which failed. When a human enters data through the terminal, they will hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which is returned from `read_line`:

   ```
   $ echo '07:05:45PM' | cargo run
   input error: expected 10 characters, got 11
   $ echo -n '07:05:45PM' | cargo run
   19:05:45
   ```
2. Style issues - learn to love [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt):

   1. There's no space before `:` when specifiying a type on a variable.
   2. Use trailing commas.
   3. Match arms longer than one line should use curly braces `{}`
3. Accept a `&str` instead of `String`; the function doesn't need to take ownership of the string.
4. There's no need for the turbofish (`::<>`) on the `parse` calls; type inference handles that just fine.
5. Become **very** familiar with all the methods on `Option` and `Result` and `Iterator`. These are the bread and butter of idiomatic, concise, and performant Rust code. Specifically, if you `match` on a `Result` and have a match arm for `Ok` and `Err`, it's likely you want to use `Result::map`.
6. Avoid iterating through the characters from the beginning multiple times, it is less efficient than needs to be. Instead, use the same iterator multiple times through `Iterator::by_ref`.
7. I'd use `expect` in your `main` method, instead of matching and printing. There is a difference between the two, `expect` will cause a panic on `Err`, but that seems reasonable in `main`.
8. I never use `unwrap`, instead preferring at least `expect`; this helps find the line when the code finally fails.
9. Library code should very rarely panic; they should report errors. Especially report errors when it's because of input supplied to the code, panic for internal logic errors.
10. The match in `read_12h_time` can be flattened; you can pattern match against `Ok(10)` directly.
11. `stdin` doesn't need to be explicitly locked; `read_line` will lock it.

```
use std::io::{stdin, Error, ErrorKind, Result};

struct Time {
    hour: u8,
    minute: u8,
    second: u8,
}

impl Time {
    pub fn from_12h(time: &str) -> Result<Time> {
        assert!(time.chars().count() == 10);
        let mut chars = time.chars();

        let hour: String = chars.by_ref().take(2).collect();
        let minute: String = chars.by_ref().skip(1).take(2).collect();
        let second: String = chars.by_ref().skip(1).take(2).collect();
        let period: String = chars.by_ref().take(2).collect();

        Time::hour_from_12h_to_24h(hour.parse().unwrap(), &period).map(|hour_24h| {
            Time {
                hour: hour_24h,
                minute: minute.parse().unwrap(),
                second: second.parse().unwrap(),
            }
        })
    }

    fn hour_from_12h_to_24h(hour: u8, period: &str) -> Result<u8> {
        match period {
            "AM" => Ok(hour % 12),
            "PM" => Ok(hour % 12 + 12),
            _ => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, format!("invalid period {}", period))),
        }
    }

    pub fn to_24h(&self) -> String {
        format!("{:02}:{:02}:{:02}", self.hour, self.minute, self.second)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let time_12h = read_12h_time().expect("input error");
    let time = Time::from_12h(&time_12h).expect("error");

    println!("{}", time.to_24h());
}

fn read_12h_time() -> Result<String> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    match read_line(&mut buffer) {
        Ok(10) => Ok(buffer),
        Ok(length) => {
            Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidInput,
                           format!("expected 10 characters, got {}", length)))
        }
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}

fn read_line(buffer: &mut String) -> Result<usize> {
    stdin().read_line(buffer)
}
```

---

On to bigger issues:

1. I don't like that the AM/PM matching and hour conversion are tangled together.

   - Instead, introduce an enumeration to handle the AM/PM.
2. It feels like 12 hour time is a *different type* from 24 time.

   - Rename existing type to something unique.
   - Store the new AM/PM enumeration.
   - Introduce new type and add conversion methods.
3. I don't like reusing `io::Error` for your own errors.

   - Introduce a custom error type. I like to use quick_error, but there are other solutions.
4. I don't like that IO is embedded inside of the logic of the library.

   - Separate IO and parsing logic and only combine them at a higher level - in this case `main`.
   - Push time-specific logic (e.g. 10 character checks) back into the library. Note that this removes the duplication of the logic in the `assert` **and** removes a panic inside the library.
5. The code doesn't fully participate in the Rust ecosystem.

   - Implement traits like `FromStr` and `From` and `Display` (perf!).
   - Derive standard traits to make it easier to use your types: `#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]` is a good set.
6. There are too many panics inside the library portion.

   - Fully utilize `Result` and `try!` or the try operator `?`.
7. There's too much unneeded allocation.

   - Instead of using characters and collecting them back to strings, operate on the incoming string and take slices instead.
   - Formatting can write directly into a formatter; there's no reason to allocate a string to just turn around and print it.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;

use std::str::FromStr;
use std::io::stdin;
use std::fmt;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
    enum Error {
        MissingMeridian {
            description("missing the meridian")
            display("Missing the meridian")
        }
        InvalidMeridian(what: String) {
            description("invalid meridian")
            display("Invalid meridian: {}", what)
        }
        MissingComponent(which: TimeComponent) {
            description("missing a time component")
            display("Missing {}", which)
        }
        InvalidComponent(which: TimeComponent, why: std::num::ParseIntError) {
            description("invalid time component")
            display("Invalid {}: {}", which, why)
            cause(why)
        }
    }
}

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Error>;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
enum Meridian {
    AnteMeridian,
    PostMeridian,
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
enum TimeComponent {
    Hour,
    Minutes,
    Seconds,
}

impl fmt::Display for TimeComponent {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        use TimeComponent::*;

        let name = match *self {
            Hour => "hour",
            Minutes => "minutes",
            Seconds => "seconds",
        };
        write!(f, "{}", name)
    }
}

impl FromStr for Meridian {
    type Err = Error;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Meridian> {
        match s {
            "AM" => Ok(Meridian::AnteMeridian),
            "PM" => Ok(Meridian::PostMeridian),
            _ => Err(Error::InvalidMeridian(s.to_string())),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct TwelveHourTime {
    hour: u8,
    minutes: u8,
    seconds: u8,
    meridian: Meridian,
}

impl FromStr for TwelveHourTime {
    type Err = Error;

    fn from_str(time: &str) -> Result<TwelveHourTime> {
        use Error::*;
        use TimeComponent::*;

        let mut parts = time.splitn(3, ":");

        let hour = parts.next().ok_or(MissingComponent(Hour))?;
        let minutes = parts.next().ok_or(MissingComponent(Minutes))?;
        let seconds_meridian = parts.next().ok_or(MissingComponent(Seconds))?;

        if seconds_meridian.len() < 4 {
            return Err(MissingMeridian);
        }

        let (seconds, meridian) = seconds_meridian.split_at(2);

        let hour = hour.parse().map_err(|e| InvalidComponent(Hour, e))?;
        let minutes = minutes.parse().map_err(|e| InvalidComponent(Minutes, e))?;
        let seconds = seconds.parse().map_err(|e| InvalidComponent(Seconds, e))?;
        let meridian = meridian.parse()?;

        Ok(TwelveHourTime {
            hour: hour,
            minutes: minutes,
            seconds: seconds,
            meridian: meridian,
        })
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct TwentyFourHourTime {
    hour: u8,
    minutes: u8,
    seconds: u8,
}

impl From<TwelveHourTime> for TwentyFourHourTime {
    fn from(other: TwelveHourTime) -> Self {
        let hour = match other.meridian {
            Meridian::AnteMeridian => other.hour,
            Meridian::PostMeridian => other.hour + 12,
        };

        TwentyFourHourTime {
            hour: hour,
            minutes: other.minutes,
            seconds: other.seconds,
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for TwentyFourHourTime {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:02}:{:02}:{:02}", self.hour, self.minutes, self.seconds)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut time = String::new();
    stdin().read_line(&mut time).expect("Unable to read input");

    let time: TwelveHourTime = time.trim().parse().expect("Unable to parse time");
    let time: TwentyFourHourTime = time.into();

    println!("{}", time);
}
```

---

> The problem is very simple, but the code seems too lengthy?

I don't suppose I made the length any better! However, I feel that the final code is pretty efficient, and when you start taking error cases into account, I would disagree that the problem is inherently "simple". Parsing text is complicated. You can use tools like regular expressions or parser combinators / generators, but those are just abstractions - the complexity is just hidden from view.

There's still logical aspects here that are strange. For example, the original code does `hours % 12`, which seems wrong, and my modified code does not, which also seems wrong! It's probably better to throw an error for invalid hourly values.